# How to add ambient Serilog properties during an MVC controller's action processing

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I'd like to add a Serilog property to all logging that occurs within the scope of a request to an ASP.NET Core controller.  The value of this property is determined by routing data.

Conceptually, this is easy, I just add something like the following to my controller:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
   var propValue = context.ActionArguments["myvalue"] as string;
   // BAD CODE DON'T COPY THIS
   LogContext.PushProperty("MyProperty", propValue);
   base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

This "works", in that it adds 'MyProperty' to every logged event all the way down for the rest of the call to this request.  However, it's clearly not the right way to do this, as the docs give strict instructions to carefully dispose calls to `LogContext.PushProperty` in the reverse order to which they were pushed.  There's nothing to say that LogContext has the same scope as the HTTP request anyway.

I thought `IDiagnosticContext` was the solution, but it only affects the Serilog's request logging, it's not a general ambient context.

The framework actually achieves exactly what I want, decorating the log context with things like 'ActionName' and 'RequestId' - but I guess it does this at some point where the scope of the request is much clearer.

Is there a simple way to add ambient Serilog properties "for the rest of the current request", or do I need to write middleware to do this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out there's an easy solution to this and that Controller has a more suitable override than `OnActionExecuting`:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var propValue = context.ActionArguments["myvalue"] as string;
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("MyProperty", propValue))
    {
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```